# google webfonts looks bad on chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, fonts, google-webfonts

I rely heavily on Google Webfonts for my site and (unfortunatly) google chrome presents them badly, i have set font-smooth to always, but it dosen't seem to help. 
EXAMPLES:

[image: Google Chrome - Londrina Outline]

[image: Firefox - Londrina Outline]

[image: Google Chrome - Walter Turncoat]

[image: Firefox - Walter Turncoat]

Is there any way i could smooth them / make them look better??

Thanks,

Comment: @abraham I think the OP wants to know if there is anything he can do to make the font look smoother.

Comment: @Connor that would be the logical guess but someone could spend an hour researching an answer just to find they answered the wrong one.

Comment: Look at http://superuser.com/questions/308135/how-can-i-improve-font-appearance-in-google-chrome
This seems to be the same problem, with more progress.

Comment: I made a detailed blog post about this incl. fixes: [How to fix the ugly font rendering in Google Chrome](http://www.dev-metal.com/fix-ugly-font-rendering-google-chrome/)

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would use

> http://www.fontsquirrel.com/

It's all hosted on your server and it's compatible with nearly every browser! Since using Font Squirrel I haven't looked elsewhere.

Comment: Font Squirrel gives the same problem as Google Web Fonts.  If the fonts aren't hinted correctly, they will only display properly at their core size.  OTF features don't work at all.  God help you if you want ligatures.

Answer (score 4):

Font rendering problems are common in GChrome, try changing the order of your @font-face sources... Chrome utilises the .svg file in the @font-face sources, in some reason it doesn´t tolerate .svg being called last in the list

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'my-dirty-font';
src: url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.eot');
src: url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.woff') format('woff'),
url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.svg') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;
}
```

If the order @font-face order looks similar then try changing to

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'my-dirty-font';
    src: url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.eot?#iefix') format('eot'),
    url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.svg') format('svg');
    url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.woff') format('woff'),
    url('../fonts/my-dirty-font.ttf') format('truetype'),
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    }
```